# 'when' statement skipping a condition in Kotlin for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I've been developing an app on android studio canary 5 using kotlin. I'm using a when statement to verify if a registration form is valid as so.

```
else if(registering) when {
        email.text == null -> email.error = "Enter Email!"
        !isValidEmail(email.text) -> email.error = "Invalid Email!"
        password.text == null -> password.error = "Enter Password!"
        password_conf.text == null -> password_conf.error = "Re-enter Password!"
        password_conf.text.toString() != password.text.toString() -> password_conf.error =
                "Re-enter Password!"
        password_conf.text.toString() != password.text.toString() -> password_conf.error = "Passwords Don't Match!"
        name.text == null -> name.error = "Enter Full Name!"
        branchSelected == "Branch" ->{
            val errorText = branch.selectedView as TextView
            errorText.error = ""
            errorText.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            errorText.text = getString(R.string.select_branch)
        }
        phone.text == null || !isValidPhone(phone.text) -> phone.error = "Enter Valid Phone Number!"
        !isValidReg(reg_number.text) -> reg_number.error = "Invalid Registration Number"
        roll_number.text != null && !isValidRoll(roll_number.text) -> roll_number.error = "Enter Valid roll number!"
        else -> {
            createAccount(email.text.toString(), password.text.toString())
            addDB()
        }
    }
```

The line `password.text == null -> password.error = "Enter Password!"` doesn't work for some reason.

I'm like 90% sure the line is correct since `email.text == null -> email.error = "Enter Email!"` works perfectly fine and android studio color codes the variables.

Can the error occur because android studio kotlin support is in beta or for some other reason?

Update: As JK Ly suggested, Here are the values of email and password:

```
(When I kept email empty)

email = {AppCompatEditText@5191} "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{c15a402 VFED..CL. .F...... 79,242-1001,360 #7f09003d app:id/email}"
 mBackgroundTintHelper = {AppCompatBackgroundHelper@5243} 
 mTextHelper = {AppCompatTextHelperV17@5244} 
 mAllowTransformationLengthChange = false
 mAutoLinkMask = 0
 mBoring = null
 mBreakStrategy = 0
 mBufferType = {TextView$BufferType@5245} "EDITABLE"
 mChangeWatcher = {TextView$ChangeWatcher@5246} 
 mCharWrapper = null
 mCurHintTextColor = 1627389952
 mCurTextColor = -570425344
 mCurrentSpellCheckerLocaleCache = null
 mCursorDrawableRes = 17303397
 mDeferScroll = -1
 mDesiredHeightAtMeasure = 118
 mDeviceProvisionedState = 0
 mDrawables = null
 mEditableFactory = {Editable$Factory@5247} 
 mEditor = {Editor@5248} 
 mEllipsize = null
 mFilters = {InputFilter[0]@5249} 
 mFreezesText = false
 mGravity = 8388627
 mHighlightColor = 1711314568
 mHighlightPaint = {Paint@5250} 
 mHighlightPath = {Path@5251} 
 mHighlightPathBogus = false
 mHint = "Email"
 mHintBoring = {BoringLayout$Metrics@5253} "FontMetricsInt: top=-50 ascent=-44 descent=11 bottom=13 leading=0 width=116"
 mHintLayout = {BoringLayout@5254} 
 mHintTextColor = {ColorStateList@5255} "ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=0mStateSpecs=[[16842910, 16842919], []]mColors=[-1979711488, 1627389952]mDefaultColor=1627389952}"
 mHorizontallyScrolling = true
 mHyphenationFrequency = 1
 mIncludePad = true
 mLastLayoutDirection = 0
 mLastScroll = 0
 mLayout = {DynamicLayout@5256} 
 mLinkTextColor = {ColorStateList@5257} "ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=0mStateSpecs=[[]]mColors=[-16738680]mDefaultColor=-16738680}"
 mLinksClickable = true
 mListeners = null
 mLocalesChanged = false
 mMarquee = null
 mMarqueeFadeMode = 0
 mMarqueeRepeatLimit = 3
 mMaxMode = 1
 mMaxWidth = 2147483647
 mMaxWidthMode = 2
 mMaximum = 1
 mMinMode = 1
 mMinWidth = 0
 mMinWidthMode = 2
 mMinimum = 1
 mMovement = {ArrowKeyMovementMethod@5258} 
 mOldMaxMode = 1
 mOldMaximum = 1
 mPreDrawListenerDetached = false
 mPreDrawRegistered = false
 mPreventDefaultMovement = false
 mRestartMarquee = false
 mSavedHintLayout = {BoringLayout@5254} 
 mSavedLayout = null
 mSavedMarqueeModeLayout = null
 mScroller = null
 mShadowColor = 0
 mShadowDx = 0.0
 mShadowDy = 0.0
 mShadowRadius = 0.0
 mSingleLine = true
 mSpacingAdd = 0.0
 mSpacingMult = 1.0
 mSpannableFactory = {Spannable$Factory@5259} 
 mTempRect = {Rect@5260} "Rect(87, 305 - 91, 423)"
 mText = {SpannableStringBuilder@5261} ""
  mFilters = {InputFilter[1]@5289} 
  mGapLength = 10
  mGapStart = 0
  mIndexOfSpan = {IdentityHashMap@5290}  size = 7
  mLowWaterMark = 2147483647
  mOrderSortBuffer = {int[9]@5291} 
  mPrioSortBuffer = {int[9]@5292} 
  mSpanCount = 7
  mSpanEnds = {int[9]@5293} 
  mSpanFlags = {int[9]@5294} 
  mSpanInsertCount = 19
  mSpanMax = {int[7]@5295} 
  mSpanOrder = {int[9]@5296} 
  mSpanStarts = {int[9]@5297} 
  mSpans = {Object[9]@5298} 
  mText = {char[10]@5299} 
  mTextWatcherDepth = 0
  shadow$_klass_ = {Class@529} "class android.text.SpannableStringBuilder"
  shadow$_monitor_ = -2077412599
 mTextColor = {ColorStateList@5262} "ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=0mStateSpecs=[[-16842910], []]mColors=[973078528, -570425344]mDefaultColor=-570425344}"
 mTextDir = {TextDirectionHeuristics$TextDirectionHeuristicInternal@5263} 
 mTextEditSuggestionContainerLayout = 17367285
 mTextEditSuggestionHighlightStyle = 16974923
 mTextEditSuggestionItemLayout = 17367287
 mTextPaint = {TextPaint@5264} 
 mTextSelectHandleLeftRes = 17303401
 mTextSelectHandleRes = 17303403
 mTextSelectHandleRightRes = 17303405
 mTransformation = {SingleLineTransformationMethod@5265} 
 mTransformed = {ReplacementTransformationMethod$SpannedReplacementCharSequence@5266} ""
 mUserSetTextScaleX = false
 mAccessibilityCursorPosition = -1
 mAccessibilityDelegate = null
 mAccessibilityTraversalAfterId = -1
 mAccessibilityTraversalBeforeId = -1
 mAccessibilityViewId = -1
 mAnimator = null
 mAttachInfo = {View$AttachInfo@5267} 
 mAttributes = null
 mBackground = {InsetDrawable@5268} 
 mBackgroundRenderNode = {RenderNode@5269} 
 mBackgroundResource = 0
 mBackgroundSizeChanged = false
 mBackgroundTint = null
 mBottom = 360
 mCachingFailed = false
 mClipBounds = null
 mContentDescription = null
 mContext = {LoginActivity@5188} 
 mCurrentAnimation = null
 mDrawableState = {int[4]@5270} 
 mDrawingCache = null
 mDrawingCacheBackgroundColor = 0
 mFloatingTreeObserver = null
 mForegroundInfo = null
 mFrameMetricsObservers = null
 mGhostView = null
 mHasPerformedLongPress = false
 mID = 2131296317
 mIgnoreNextUpEvent = false
 mInContextButtonPress = false
 mInputEventConsistencyVerifier = null
 mKeyedTags = null
 mLabelForId = -1
 mLastIsOpaque = false
 mLayerPaint = null
 mLayerType = 0
 mLayoutInsets = null
 mLayoutParams = {LinearLayout$LayoutParams@5271} 
 mLeft = 79
 mLeftPaddingDefined = false
 mListenerInfo = null
 mLongClickX = NaN
 mLongClickY = NaN
 mMatchIdPredicate = null
 mMatchLabelForPredicate = null
 mMeasureCache = {LongSparseLongArray@5272} "{4611689978387236305=3959959847030}"
 mMeasuredHeight = 118
 mMeasuredWidth = 922
 mMinHeight = 0
 View.mMinWidth = 0
 mNestedScrollingParent = null
 mNextFocusDownId = -1
 mNextFocusForwardId = -1
 mNextFocusLeftId = -1
 mNextFocusRightId = -1
 mNextFocusUpId = -1
 mOldHeightMeasureSpec = 1489
 mOldWidthMeasureSpec = 1073742746
 mOutlineProvider = {ViewOutlineProvider$1@5273} 
 mOverScrollMode = 1
 mOverlay = null
 mPaddingBottom = 29
 mPaddingLeft = 10
 mPaddingRight = 10
 mPaddingTop = 26
 mParent = {LinearLayout@5274} "android.widget.LinearLayout{2b0397d V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1997 #7f090000 app:id/SignIn_Layout}"
 mPendingCheckForLongPress = null
 mPendingCheckForTap = null
 mPerformClick = null
 mPointerIcon = null
 mPrivateFlags = 16812082
 mPrivateFlags2 = 1611867688
 mPrivateFlags3 = 4
 mRecreateDisplayList = false
 mRenderNode = {RenderNode@5275} 
 mResources = {Resources@5227} 
 mRight = 1001
 mRightPaddingDefined = false
 mRunQueue = {HandlerActionQueue@5276} 
 mScrollCache = null
 mScrollIndicatorDrawable = null
 mScrollX = 0
 mScrollY = 0
 mSendViewScrolledAccessibilityEvent = null
 mSendViewStateChangedAccessibilityEvent = null
 mSendingHoverAccessibilityEvents = false
 mStartActivityRequestWho = null
 mStateListAnimator = null
 mSystemUiVisibility = 0
 mTag = null
 mTempNestedScrollConsumed = null
 mTop = 242
 mTouchDelegate = null
 mTouchSlop = 21
 mTransformationInfo = {View$TransformationInfo@5277} 
 mTransientStateCount = 0
 mTransitionName = null
 mUnscaledDrawingCache = null
 mUnsetPressedState = null
 mUserPaddingBottom = 29
 mUserPaddingEnd = -2147483648
 mUserPaddingLeft = 10
 mUserPaddingLeftInitial = 10
 mUserPaddingRight = 10
 mUserPaddingRightInitial = 10
 mUserPaddingStart = -2147483648
 mVerticalScrollFactor = 0.0
 mVerticalScrollbarPosition = 0
 mViewFlags = 405028865
 mWindowAttachCount = 1
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@5076} "class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1944738814  


(When I gave some value of email)


email = {AppCompatEditText@5199} "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{9041f8b VFED..CL. .F...... 79,242-1001,360 #7f09003d app:id/email}"
 mBackgroundTintHelper = {AppCompatBackgroundHelper@5250} 
 mTextHelper = {AppCompatTextHelperV17@5251} 
 mAllowTransformationLengthChange = false
 mAutoLinkMask = 0
 mBoring = null
 mBreakStrategy = 0
 mBufferType = {TextView$BufferType@5252} "EDITABLE"
 mChangeWatcher = {TextView$ChangeWatcher@5253} 
 mCharWrapper = null
 mCurHintTextColor = 1627389952
 mCurTextColor = -570425344
 mCurrentSpellCheckerLocaleCache = null
 mCursorDrawableRes = 17303397
 mDeferScroll = -1
 mDesiredHeightAtMeasure = 118
 mDeviceProvisionedState = 0
 mDrawables = null
 mEditableFactory = {Editable$Factory@5254} 
 mEditor = {Editor@5255} 
 mEllipsize = null
 mFilters = {InputFilter[0]@5256} 
 mFreezesText = false
 mGravity = 8388627
 mHighlightColor = 1711314568
 mHighlightPaint = {Paint@5257} 
 mHighlightPath = {Path@5258} 
 mHighlightPathBogus = false
 mHint = "Email"
 mHintBoring = {BoringLayout$Metrics@5260} "FontMetricsInt: top=-50 ascent=-44 descent=11 bottom=13 leading=0 width=116"
 mHintLayout = {BoringLayout@5261} 
 mHintTextColor = {ColorStateList@5262} "ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=0mStateSpecs=[[16842910, 16842919], []]mColors=[-1979711488, 1627389952]mDefaultColor=1627389952}"
 mHorizontallyScrolling = true
 mHyphenationFrequency = 1
 mIncludePad = true
 mLastLayoutDirection = 0
 mLastScroll = 0
 mLayout = {DynamicLayout@5263} 
 mLinkTextColor = {ColorStateList@5264} "ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=0mStateSpecs=[[]]mColors=[-16738680]mDefaultColor=-16738680}"
 mLinksClickable = true
 mListeners = null
 mLocalesChanged = false
 mMarquee = null
 mMarqueeFadeMode = 0
 mMarqueeRepeatLimit = 3
 mMaxMode = 1
 mMaxWidth = 2147483647
 mMaxWidthMode = 2
 mMaximum = 1
 mMinMode = 1
 mMinWidth = 0
 mMinWidthMode = 2
 mMinimum = 1
 mMovement = {ArrowKeyMovementMethod@5265} 
 mOldMaxMode = 1
 mOldMaximum = 1
 mPreDrawListenerDetached = false
 mPreDrawRegistered = false
 mPreventDefaultMovement = false
 mRestartMarquee = false
 mSavedHintLayout = {BoringLayout@5261} 
 mSavedLayout = null
 mSavedMarqueeModeLayout = null
 mScroller = null
 mShadowColor = 0
 mShadowDx = 0.0
 mShadowDy = 0.0
 mShadowRadius = 0.0
 mSingleLine = true
 mSpacingAdd = 0.0
 mSpacingMult = 1.0
 mSpannableFactory = {Spannable$Factory@5266} 
 mTempRect = {Rect@5267} "Rect(374, 305 - 378, 423)"
 mText = {SpannableStringBuilder@5268} "wfm@dm.ssc"
 mTextColor = {ColorStateList@5269} "ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=0mStateSpecs=[[-16842910], []]mColors=[973078528, -570425344]mDefaultColor=-570425344}"
 mTextDir = {TextDirectionHeuristics$TextDirectionHeuristicInternal@5270} 
 mTextEditSuggestionContainerLayout = 17367285
 mTextEditSuggestionHighlightStyle = 16974923
 mTextEditSuggestionItemLayout = 17367287
 mTextPaint = {TextPaint@5271} 
 mTextSelectHandleLeftRes = 17303401
 mTextSelectHandleRes = 17303403
 mTextSelectHandleRightRes = 17303405
 mTransformation = {SingleLineTransformationMethod@5272} 
 mTransformed = {ReplacementTransformationMethod$SpannedReplacementCharSequence@5273} "wfm@dm.ssc"
 mUserSetTextScaleX = false
 mAccessibilityCursorPosition = -1
 mAccessibilityDelegate = null
 mAccessibilityTraversalAfterId = -1
 mAccessibilityTraversalBeforeId = -1
 mAccessibilityViewId = -1
 mAnimator = null
 mAttachInfo = {View$AttachInfo@5274} 
 mAttributes = null
 mBackground = {InsetDrawable@5275} 
 mBackgroundRenderNode = {RenderNode@5276} 
 mBackgroundResource = 0
 mBackgroundSizeChanged = false
 mBackgroundTint = null
 mBottom = 360
 mCachingFailed = false
 mClipBounds = null
 mContentDescription = null
 mContext = {LoginActivity@5195} 
 mCurrentAnimation = null
 mDrawableState = {int[4]@5277} 
 mDrawingCache = null
 mDrawingCacheBackgroundColor = 0
 mFloatingTreeObserver = null
 mForegroundInfo = null
 mFrameMetricsObservers = null
 mGhostView = null
 mHasPerformedLongPress = false
 mID = 2131296317
 mIgnoreNextUpEvent = false
 mInContextButtonPress = false
 mInputEventConsistencyVerifier = null
 mKeyedTags = null
 mLabelForId = -1
 mLastIsOpaque = false
 mLayerPaint = null
 mLayerType = 0
 mLayoutInsets = null
 mLayoutParams = {LinearLayout$LayoutParams@5278} 
 mLeft = 79
 mLeftPaddingDefined = false
 mListenerInfo = null
 mLongClickX = NaN
 mLongClickY = NaN
 mMatchIdPredicate = null
 mMatchLabelForPredicate = null
 mMeasureCache = {LongSparseLongArray@5279} "{4611689978387236305=3959959847030}"
 mMeasuredHeight = 118
 mMeasuredWidth = 922
 mMinHeight = 0
 View.mMinWidth = 0
 mNestedScrollingParent = null
 mNextFocusDownId = -1
 mNextFocusForwardId = -1
 mNextFocusLeftId = -1
 mNextFocusRightId = -1
 mNextFocusUpId = -1
 mOldHeightMeasureSpec = 1489
 mOldWidthMeasureSpec = 1073742746
 mOutlineProvider = {ViewOutlineProvider$1@5280} 
 mOverScrollMode = 1
 mOverlay = null
 mPaddingBottom = 29
 mPaddingLeft = 10
 mPaddingRight = 10
 mPaddingTop = 26
 mParent = {LinearLayout@5281} "android.widget.LinearLayout{bd21b35 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1997 #7f090000 app:id/SignIn_Layout}"
 mPendingCheckForLongPress = null
 mPendingCheckForTap = null
 mPerformClick = null
 mPointerIcon = null
 mPrivateFlags = 16812082
 mPrivateFlags2 = 1611867688
 mPrivateFlags3 = 4
 mRecreateDisplayList = false
 mRenderNode = {RenderNode@5282} 
 mResources = {Resources@5234} 
 mRight = 1001
 mRightPaddingDefined = false
 mRunQueue = {HandlerActionQueue@5283} 
 mScrollCache = null
 mScrollIndicatorDrawable = null
 mScrollX = 0
 mScrollY = 0
 mSendViewScrolledAccessibilityEvent = null
 mSendViewStateChangedAccessibilityEvent = null
 mSendingHoverAccessibilityEvents = false
 mStartActivityRequestWho = null
 mStateListAnimator = null
 mSystemUiVisibility = 0
 mTag = null
 mTempNestedScrollConsumed = null
 mTop = 242
 mTouchDelegate = null
 mTouchSlop = 21
 mTransformationInfo = {View$TransformationInfo@5284} 
 mTransientStateCount = 0
 mTransitionName = null
 mUnscaledDrawingCache = null
 mUnsetPressedState = null
 mUserPaddingBottom = 29
 mUserPaddingEnd = -2147483648
 mUserPaddingLeft = 10
 mUserPaddingLeftInitial = 10
 mUserPaddingRight = 10
 mUserPaddingRightInitial = 10
 mUserPaddingStart = -2147483648
 mVerticalScrollFactor = 0.0
 mVerticalScrollbarPosition = 0
 mViewFlags = 405028865
 mWindowAttachCount = 1
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@5076} "class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1996218485  


password = {AppCompatEditText@5200} "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{8dff868 VFED..CL. ........ 79,400-1001,518 #7f090075 app:id/password}"
 mBackgroundTintHelper = {AppCompatBackgroundHelper@5308} 
 mTextHelper = {AppCompatTextHelperV17@5309} 
 mAllowTransformationLengthChange = false
 mAutoLinkMask = 0
 mBoring = null
 mBreakStrategy = 0
 mBufferType = {TextView$BufferType@5252} "EDITABLE"
 mChangeWatcher = {TextView$ChangeWatcher@5310} 
 mCharWrapper = null
 mCurHintTextColor = 1627389952
 mCurTextColor = -570425344
 mCurrentSpellCheckerLocaleCache = null
 mCursorDrawableRes = 17303397
 mDeferScroll = -1
 mDesiredHeightAtMeasure = 118
 mDeviceProvisionedState = 0
 mDrawables = null
 mEditableFactory = {Editable$Factory@5254} 
 mEditor = {Editor@5311} 
 mEllipsize = null
 mFilters = {InputFilter[0]@5256} 
 mFreezesText = false
 mGravity = 8388627
 mHighlightColor = 1711314568
 mHighlightPaint = {Paint@5312} 
 mHighlightPath = null
 mHighlightPathBogus = true
 mHint = "Password"
 mHintBoring = {BoringLayout$Metrics@5314} "FontMetricsInt: top=-50 ascent=-44 descent=11 bottom=13 leading=0 width=224"
 mHintLayout = {BoringLayout@5315} 
 mHintTextColor = {ColorStateList@5262} "ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=0mStateSpecs=[[16842910, 16842919], []]mColors=[-1979711488, 1627389952]mDefaultColor=1627389952}"
 mHorizontallyScrolling = true
 mHyphenationFrequency = 1
 mIncludePad = true
 mLastLayoutDirection = 0
 mLastScroll = 0
 mLayout = {DynamicLayout@5316} 
 mLinkTextColor = {ColorStateList@5264} "ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=0mStateSpecs=[[]]mColors=[-16738680]mDefaultColor=-16738680}"
 mLinksClickable = true
 mListeners = null
 mLocalesChanged = false
 mMarquee = null
 mMarqueeFadeMode = 0
 mMarqueeRepeatLimit = 3
 mMaxMode = 1
 mMaxWidth = 2147483647
 mMaxWidthMode = 2
 mMaximum = 1
 mMinMode = 1
 mMinWidth = 0
 mMinWidthMode = 2
 mMinimum = 1
 mMovement = {ArrowKeyMovementMethod@5265} 
 mOldMaxMode = 1
 mOldMaximum = 1
 mPreDrawListenerDetached = false
 mPreDrawRegistered = false
 mPreventDefaultMovement = false
 mRestartMarquee = false
 mSavedHintLayout = {BoringLayout@5315} 
 mSavedLayout = null
 mSavedMarqueeModeLayout = null
 mScroller = null
 mShadowColor = 0
 mShadowDx = 0.0
 mShadowDy = 0.0
 mShadowRadius = 0.0
 mSingleLine = true
 mSpacingAdd = 0.0
 mSpacingMult = 1.0
 mSpannableFactory = {Spannable$Factory@5266} 
 mTempRect = null
 mText = {SpannableStringBuilder@5317} ""
 mTextColor = {ColorStateList@5269} "ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=0mStateSpecs=[[-16842910], []]mColors=[973078528, -570425344]mDefaultColor=-570425344}"
 mTextDir = {TextDirectionHeuristics$TextDirectionHeuristicInternal@5318} 
 mTextEditSuggestionContainerLayout = 17367285
 mTextEditSuggestionHighlightStyle = 16974923
 mTextEditSuggestionItemLayout = 17367287
 mTextPaint = {TextPaint@5319} 
 mTextSelectHandleLeftRes = 17303401
 mTextSelectHandleRes = 17303403
 mTextSelectHandleRightRes = 17303405
 mTransformation = {PasswordTransformationMethod@5320} 
 mTransformed = {PasswordTransformationMethod$PasswordCharSequence@5321} ""
 mUserSetTextScaleX = false
 mAccessibilityCursorPosition = -1
 mAccessibilityDelegate = null
 mAccessibilityTraversalAfterId = -1
 mAccessibilityTraversalBeforeId = -1
 mAccessibilityViewId = -1
 mAnimator = null
 mAttachInfo = {View$AttachInfo@5274} 
 mAttributes = null
 mBackground = {InsetDrawable@5322} 
 mBackgroundRenderNode = {RenderNode@5323} 
 mBackgroundResource = 0
 mBackgroundSizeChanged = false
 mBackgroundTint = null
 mBottom = 518
 mCachingFailed = false
 mClipBounds = null
 mContentDescription = null
 mContext = {LoginActivity@5195} 
 mCurrentAnimation = null
 mDrawableState = {int[3]@5324} 
 mDrawingCache = null
 mDrawingCacheBackgroundColor = 0
 mFloatingTreeObserver = null
 mForegroundInfo = null
 mFrameMetricsObservers = null
 mGhostView = null
 mHasPerformedLongPress = false
 mID = 2131296373
 mIgnoreNextUpEvent = false
 mInContextButtonPress = false
 mInputEventConsistencyVerifier = null
 mKeyedTags = null
 mLabelForId = -1
 mLastIsOpaque = false
 mLayerPaint = null
 mLayerType = 0
 mLayoutInsets = null
 mLayoutParams = {LinearLayout$LayoutParams@5278} 
 mLeft = 79
 mLeftPaddingDefined = false
 mListenerInfo = null
 mLongClickX = NaN
 mLongClickY = NaN
 mMatchIdPredicate = null
 mMatchLabelForPredicate = null
 mMeasureCache = {LongSparseLongArray@5325} "{4611689978387236147=3959959847030}"
 mMeasuredHeight = 118
 mMeasuredWidth = 922
 mMinHeight = 0
 View.mMinWidth = 0
 mNestedScrollingParent = null
 mNextFocusDownId = -1
 mNextFocusForwardId = -1
 mNextFocusLeftId = -1
 mNextFocusRightId = -1
 mNextFocusUpId = -1
 mOldHeightMeasureSpec = 1331
 mOldWidthMeasureSpec = 1073742746
 mOutlineProvider = {ViewOutlineProvider$1@5280} 
 mOverScrollMode = 1
 mOverlay = null
 mPaddingBottom = 29
 mPaddingLeft = 10
 mPaddingRight = 10
 mPaddingTop = 26
 mParent = {LinearLayout@5281} "android.widget.LinearLayout{bd21b35 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1997 #7f090000 app:id/SignIn_Layout}"
 mPendingCheckForLongPress = null
 mPendingCheckForTap = null
 mPerformClick = null
 mPointerIcon = null
 mPrivateFlags = 16812080
 mPrivateFlags2 = 1611867688
 mPrivateFlags3 = 4
 mRecreateDisplayList = false
 mRenderNode = {RenderNode@5326} 
 mResources = {Resources@5234} 
 mRight = 1001
 mRightPaddingDefined = false
 mRunQueue = null
 mScrollCache = null
 mScrollIndicatorDrawable = null
 mScrollX = 0
 mScrollY = 0
 mSendViewScrolledAccessibilityEvent = null
 mSendViewStateChangedAccessibilityEvent = null
 mSendingHoverAccessibilityEvents = false
 mStartActivityRequestWho = null
 mStateListAnimator = null
 mSystemUiVisibility = 0
 mTag = null
 mTempNestedScrollConsumed = null
 mTop = 400
 mTouchDelegate = null
 mTouchSlop = 21
 mTransformationInfo = {View$TransformationInfo@5327} 
 mTransientStateCount = 0
 mTransitionName = null
 mUnscaledDrawingCache = null
 mUnsetPressedState = null
 mUserPaddingBottom = 29
 mUserPaddingEnd = -2147483648
 mUserPaddingLeft = 10
 mUserPaddingLeftInitial = 10
 mUserPaddingRight = 10
 mUserPaddingRightInitial = 10
 mUserPaddingStart = -2147483648
 mVerticalScrollFactor = 0.0
 mVerticalScrollbarPosition = 0
 mViewFlags = 405028865
 mWindowAttachCount = 1
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@5076} "class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1998587800
```

Comment: Do you get an error message on the line `password.text == null -> password.error = "Enter Password!"`? If so, what is it exactly?

Comment: No, I don't get an error. even when I Keep the password field null, it still doesn't raise the required error, i.e. "Invalid Password!"

Comment: What is the type of `email` and `password`?

Comment: Can you leave a breakpoint on the line starting `else if(registering)`, and then up date the question showing us the state of `email` and `password`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `password.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty()` to achieve the desired result.
No idea why `email.text == null` works but `password.text == null` does not. Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0):

If no argument is supplied `when` is used as a replacement for an `if-else if`
Everything works fine. You got one valid statement and then out of `when`
[Kotlin When Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html)

Comment: No, I know that. What I mean is that I give the email but leave the password out on purpose, but I still don't get an error message

Comment: So `password.text == null` is not null ) Try to use debugger or logs and check `password` variable. There is some thing wrong

Comment: I have been trying to do that. My issue is that the same line works well and fine when used on the edit text named email but fails when used the edit text named password. How do I make it that the error is shown when password field is empty